# Remove or install command is not working in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to remove unzip from ubuntu 16  but not able to delete it coomand is not showing any output after confirmation.

```
HP-Laptop-15q-ds0xxx:~$ sudo apt-get remove unzip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  file-roller ubuntu-desktop unzip
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
29 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 2,584 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
HP-Laptop-15q-ds0xxx:~$
```

After running remove command it is still showing me the unzip and it still working. Same thing is happening with other apt-get install or apt-get remove command

```
HP-Laptop-15q-ds0xxx:~$ unzip -v
UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.
```

Comment: Please migrate this to Super User.

Comment: you mean after sudo su

Comment: No, migrate this question to the Super User Stack Exchange forum.